# pygame window opens and instantly closes

Tags: pygame

So I have a file in the same folder as the file i'm coding right now and when the code runs in pycharm, if I press left arrow the other file is opened, but if I open the file using python straight from the file location it just opens and closes. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import subprocess
pygame.init()
GUI = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("The incredible guessing game")
x = 284
y = 250
width = 68
length =  250
run = True
while run:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run =False
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
 command = "python AhjaiyGame.py"
 subprocess.call(command)

pygame.draw.rect(GUI, (255,210,0), (x,y,length,width))
pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: for loop in your code should be part of the above while loop. And if statement with condition event.type=pygame.KEYDOWN should be part of for loop. And statement for drawing rectangle should be part of a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, the program exists because it has completed running.

Python is tabulation based, and in the code you posted, the `while` loop is not actually doing anything.

You need to indent the code you need looped:

```
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run =False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            command = "python AhjaiyGame.py"
            subprocess.call(command)

    pygame.draw.rect(GUI, (255,210,0), (x,y,length,width))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Notice the tabulation.

In this example, `pygame.quit()` will only be called when `run` becomes `False` and the *while* loop completes.

Comment: can you help me edit my code to do this. It would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I missed the fact that you did have a _while_ in there. See my updated answer. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Will tell you if it worked

Comment: I added it to my code but it still does not seem to work

Comment: @HamiClash this solution works for me, drawing a yellow rectangle. I'd suggest you closely check your indentation.

Comment: I fixed it :). I was not running it with the right Python. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import subprocess
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("The incredible guessing game")

x = 40
y = 30
width = 10
height =  20
vel=0.1
run = True
while run:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
     run =False
 keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
 if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
      x-=vel
 if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
      x+=vel
 if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
      y-=vel
 if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
      y+=vel
 win.fill((0,0,0))         
 pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), (x,y,width,height))
 pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```